# Rake metaprogramming: How to create multiple tasks from list

Tags: ruby, rake, capistrano, metaprogramming

Actually something I want for a Capistrano script (which is rake-based).

How do I convert several tasks like this:

```
desc 'Runs rake db:seed'
task :seed do
  on roles :db do
    within release_path do
      with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
        execute :rake, "db:seed"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Into something like this:

```
task_list = %i(
  db:seed
  db:reset
  db:migrate
  db:seed:testusers
  db:seed:testorders
)

task_list.each do |task_name|
  desc %(Runs rake #{task_name})
  task :task_name do
    on roles :db do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :rake, task_name
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

My problem being that the `task_name` is being used as a key for an environment setting in the task definition.

How can I define multiple tasks this way?

Comment: You want `task task_name`, not `task :task_name`. The former will create a task whose name is the value of the variable `task_name`. The latter will create a task named `:task_name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
task_list = %i(
  db:seed
  db:reset
  db:migrate
  db:seed:testusers
  db:seed:testorders
)

task_list.each do |task_name|
  desc %(Runs rake #{task_name})
  task {task_name => [:set_rails_env]} do
    on primary fetch(:migration_role) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :rake, task_name
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Edit: Seeing that you changed the signature from `task_name: [:dependency]` to the simpler `task_name`, you would have to do:

```
task_list.each do |task_name|
  desc %(Runs rake #{task_name})
  task task_name do
    ...
  end
end
```

The reason for the above is that `task_name: :foo` is syntactic sugar for `:task_name => :foo`. Since you want your key to be dynamically evaluated, you change the hash to read `task_name => :foo`, where `task_name` is a variable holding a symbol.

In other words - You don't want your task to be called literally `task_name` - You want it to be called that which your variable `task_name` contains.

Comment: Thanks for a super-fast response :) Wrapping the task name in a block seems interesting. Actually seeing this, I realize I have to define it ruby2-style blocks. Name `{ :name => val }` has to change to `{name: val}`.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to change the question syntax. Which actually makes your response easier and more correct.

Comment: They are not blocks, they are hashes. Ruby uses curly brackets for both, even though they are actually quite different constructs. It helps to know that `foo: :bar` is equivalent to `:foo => :bar`.