# Model unavailable in .rake file while metaprogramming rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, metaprogramming, rake

I'm trying to [generate a set of rake tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35156860/241142) based on database records, but my model is not available

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Report
```

Of course I'm not trying to use it *inside the rake task* because I need to *have it* already before I name the task.  Is there any reason it's not available by default in that scope?

Requiring `app/models/report` just leads to

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord
```

and if I require `app/models/report` and `app/model/application_record`, I get

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool with 'primary' found.
```

which makes it look like I'm going to have a long chain of untangling what autoloading normally handles for us automatically.

(I'm in a Rails 6.0 app with `config.load_defaults 5.2`, so it's still using Classic autoloading, if that matters.)

What's the most straightforward path to resolving this, so that I have what I need?

(I realize that these things are presumably intentionally left out of this scope to make `rake -T` faster, and there will be a cost to making them available, but I'd like to try it and see what the performance is like, and decide whether it's worth doing or not.)

UPDATE:

So far, chasing down all the errors, my `report.rake` file starts with

```
require_relative "../../app/models/application_record"
require_relative "../../app/models/report"

require "active_record"
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/database.yml")[Rails.env])

task_list = Report.pluck(:task)
```

and I'm stuck at

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.004 seconds); all pooled connections were in use
```

Comment: What happens if you add this, `class Report < ActiveRecord::Base; end` inside the rake task?

Comment: You mean inside the rake file?

Comment: Inside `task task_name do ... end`. Why aren't you doing `task_list.each do |task_name| ` approach from that answer?

Comment: @razvans: adding the class in the rake file doesn't do any more than requiring the report model.  I have to _**get**_ the task_list from the database before I can use it.  Once I can get it, the rest is easy.

Comment: Can you add your entire rakefile or at least the relevant parts? Normally in a rake file you use `task mytask_name: :environment do` to pass the rails environment into Rake. You should not have to be requiring anything or setting up the connection. https://www.bigbinary.com/learn-rubyonrails-book/setting-up-rake-tasks